# What's the best way to call a Property setter by name?

Tags: objective-c

I'm building a generic UI that can hook into a range of underlying object properties, so I'd like to call the getter and setter by name.  I've played around with using NSInvocation, and have also seen others use `setValue:forKey`.  But I'd like to use the fastest method.

If I hold reference to the NSInvocation instance, I can call invoke pretty rapidly, but I have a problem - how do I call a property setter using it?  It works great on the getter like so:

```
SEL propSelector = NSSelectorFromString(propertyName);
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[target class]instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:propSelector]];
[inv setSelector:propSelector];
[inv setTarget:target];
[inv invoke];
float value;
[inv getReturnValue:&value];
```

But I haven't been able to find a way to assign a value to the selector.  Using `setArgument:atIndex:` doesn't seem to work.

So, I fall back on the `setValue:forKey:` method, but I'm concerned about performance hitting this rapidly over time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve, but I've quickly tested the performance of `valueForKey:` versus your invocation method. In my tests, code below, `valueForKey:` is almost 5 times faster than the NSInvocation method.

1. 1.620685 millisec
2. 30.357355 millisec
3. 7.593611 millisec

Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>


@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    NSNumber *value;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *value;

@end

@implementation Foo

@synthesize value;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [value release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

#pragma mark MAIN
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // prepare loops
    NSUInteger i;
    NSUInteger max = 10000;
    Foo *target = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
    target.value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.345f];
    NSString *valueKey = @"value";

    // prepare mach timebase
    mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
    double ticksToNanoseconds = (double)timebase.numer / timebase.denom;

    // old-fashioned
    uint64_t startTime = mach_absolute_time();
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        NSNumber *numValue = [target valueForKey:valueKey];
    }
    uint64_t elapsedTime = mach_absolute_time() - startTime;
    double elapsedTimeInNanoseconds = elapsedTime * ticksToNanoseconds;
    NSLog(@"1: %f millisec", elapsedTimeInNanoseconds / 1000000);

    // invocation
    startTime = mach_absolute_time();
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        SEL propSelector = NSSelectorFromString(valueKey);
        NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[target class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:propSelector]];
        [inv setSelector:propSelector];
        [inv setTarget:target];
        [inv invoke];
        NSNumber *numValue;
        [inv getReturnValue:&numValue];
    }
    elapsedTime = mach_absolute_time() - startTime;
    elapsedTimeInNanoseconds = elapsedTime * ticksToNanoseconds;
    NSLog(@"2: %f millisec", elapsedTimeInNanoseconds / 1000000);

    // reused invocation
    SEL propSelector = NSSelectorFromString(valueKey);
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[target class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:propSelector]];

    startTime = mach_absolute_time();
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        [inv setSelector:propSelector];
        [inv setTarget:target];
        [inv invoke];
        NSNumber *numValue;
        [inv getReturnValue:&numValue];
    }
    elapsedTime = mach_absolute_time() - startTime;
    elapsedTimeInNanoseconds = elapsedTime * ticksToNanoseconds;
    NSLog(@"3: %f millisec", elapsedTimeInNanoseconds / 1000000);

    // clean and return
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd give you the vote, except you were spinning up an NSInvocation every step of the loop.  I modified the code to execute the setter (what I'm most interested in) and then run 3 tests.  1 - setValue:forKey:, 2 - NSInvocation (your code), and 3 - NSInvocation reusing the NSInvocation instance.  Results?  1 - 4.395584ms, 2 - 24.757238ms, 3 - 2.674826.  Looks like setValue:forKey is pretty optimized, but NSInvocation is about 40% faster if managed properly.

Comment: Ah, what the heck, I'll give you the vote anyhow...as long as folks read my comment regarding the reuse of an NSIncovation instance.  :)

Comment: I didn't reuse the NSInvocation because I wanted to test the performance of the whole operation. If you keep the NSInvocation and don't create new instances, but reuse the existing one, then yes, you are right with testing the performance of the reuse. I'll add that to the code for completeness sake. :)

Comment: Looks like the `floatValue` call additionally present in the first loop caused the biggest slowdown, without it `valueForKey:` is still faster than a reused NSInvocation.

Comment: This is a very handy benchmark.  I added a fourth test with just plain calls to `[target value]`. It was 8x faster than the loop with the KVC call.

Answer (score 0):

`setArgument:atIndex:` does work, but you have to change the name of the selector to the correct form. That is, `set` + propertyNameWithCapitalizedFirstLetter + `:`.

Comment: I know I can be explicit by crafting a string to match the setter name, but that doesn't always work properly - I'll post an example if you're interested.  I'm just confused as to why you can hit the getter by simply using NSSelectorFromString(propertyName) and not constructing the "getPropertyName:" string, but can't seem to hit the setter from the same selector.

Comment: Ah, but the (default) name of the getter generated by the `@property` mechanism is just `propertyName`, not `getPropertyName` (and no colon). I would be interested in the example of the form not working for the setter.

Answer (score 0):

setValue:forKey: is definitely the correct way to go about this. A number of pieces of Cocoa use this mechanism. If I recall correctly, the Objective-C dot syntax for properties is actually just translated to setValue:forKey:/valueForKey: (or at least something functionally similar) at compile time. If I were you I would use that until such a point as you can identify, with actual measurements, that it is negatively impacting the speed. Otherwise you are operating an a strange and non-idiomatic way for no real benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to be worried about the performance `setValue:forKey:`. It necessarily has significant overhead over a direct message to the object. *However*, as with all performance optimization questions, you should *not* prematurely write extra (or hard-to-maintain) code until you can *prove* that the performance hit is unacceptable *in your use case*. `setValue:forKey:` is probably the correct solution in your situation.

Under the hood, `setValue:forKey:` must do something like the `NSInvocation` dance you're trying. I suspect, however, that it will do it at least as well (and likely much better) than your first several attempts. `setValue:forKey:` is, after all, a core piece of the Cocoa framework and you can bet that Apple engineers have optimized the hell out of it.

Comment: See my comment above re: performance.  Yah, if used out of the box, setValue:forKey is pretty quick, but still not the quickest.