# How do you call a property setter by name?

Tags: objective-c

I've asked a related question, but thought I'd split this out into its own question.  See the code below for calling a property **getter**.

```
SEL propSelector = NSSelectorFromString(propertyName);
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[target class]instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:propSelector]];
[inv setSelector:propSelector];
[inv setTarget:target];
[inv invoke];
float value;
[inv getReturnValue:&value];
```

I'd like to do the same thing, but call the property **SETTER**.  I'd also like to avoid manually crafting the setter name by building a `@"setPropertyName:"` string.   Bottom line - is it possible to use the selector created on this line to call the **setter**?

```
SEL propSelector = NSSelectorFromString(propertyName);
```

Comment: Why are you doing any of the above? You can just call `object.propertyName` as the getter, and `object.propertyName = blah` as the setter, or use `[object propertyName]` and `[object setPropertyName:blah]` to achieve the same results...

Comment: Yes, I know you can hit setters and getters directly.  :)  I'm building a generic set of UI controls that can hook up to a variety of objects.  The controls don't need to know what they're controlling.  They just call the getter and setter for a named property of a target instance passed into the ctor.

Comment: NSInvocation ... nice.  Using regular NSSelectorFromString() does not work on Properties directly.  After some experimentation, and seeing your posting here, using the NSInvocation does work wonderfully with properties.  Thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Key-Value Coding.

I.e. `[someObject setValue: anObjectValue forKey: @"foo"];`

Comment: This really is the best way to go, as setters and getters may be different from property names (i.e. `isSomething`, `setSomething:`)

Comment: I was specifically looking for a way to do it with NSInvocation, as I was concerned about performance but in my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549815/whats-the-best-way-to-call-a-property-setter-by-name setValue:forKey is pretty fast.

Comment: Don't optimize until you measure;   I'd be surprised if either setValue:forKey: or NSInvocation showed up as overhead in anything that interacts with user interface.   If this is targeted more at the model layer, it may be problematic.  However, that'd also indicate a more likely architectural problem than a specific in-the-small performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having read your other question earlier today, this is what I can come up with:

It's not possible to use it directly as the setter. The getter does not accept any arguments, so your selector will never have the colon, so it's never gonna work.

Easiest thing to do is define your setter methods as `foo:` instead of `setFoo:`. This way you'll only have to append the colon (which is quite cheap, requires only two extra strings)

Comment: Thanks - I wish it were that easy, but some of the objects being controlled are 3rd party libraries and I'd rather not write wrappers for everything.  That'd kinda' undermine any dev time efficiencies I'd be gaining by writing such a generic set of controls.